# Returns the whole document in find query - Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Assume I have document as;

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "alex",
  adress: [
    {type: "home" , street: "flower"},
    {type: "business" , street: "falls"},
    {type: "xxx" , street: "xxx"},
  ]
}
```

I want to get `home` adress. In order to get this, I wrote the following query;

```
db.collection.find({id: 1, "adress.type" : "home"})
```

As a result of this query it returned me;

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "alex",
  adress: [
    {type: "home" , street: "flower"},
    {type: "business" , street: "falls"},
    {type: "xxx" , street: "xxx"},
  ]
}
```

However what I want is to get only `home adress` ;

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "alex",
  adress: [
    {type: "home" , street: "flower"}
  ]
}
```

How can I narrow the result of this query? How should I wrote the query in order to get only the `home adress`?

---

### edit after trying the answers from @SagarReddy and @suzo. Their answers are correct if I have one match.

The answers are not applicable in the following case;

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "alex",
  adress: [
    {type: "home" , street: "flower"},
    {type: "business" , street: "falls"},
    {type: "home" , street: "instinct"},
    {type: "xxx" , street: "xxx"},
  ]
}
```

`db.collection.find({id: 1, "adress.type" : "home"}, {"adress.$":1})` returns;

```
{ 
    id: 1
    "adress" : [
        {
            "type" : "home", 
            "street" : "flower"
        }
    ]
}
```

which is not true. It gets only one match.

What do you I expect is;

```
{ 
"id" : 1, 
"name" : "alex", 
"adress" : [
    {
        "type" : "home", 
        "street" : "flower"
    }, 
    {
        "type" : "home", 
        "street" : "instinct"
    }
]
```

}

So question is still valid. How can I get only the matched parts in mongodb find query?

Comment: Use [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) in find

Comment: Use `db.collection.find({id: 1, "adress.type" : "home"}, {"adress.$":1})`

Comment: @SagarReddy Your answer is true if and only if there is one match. Please check my update in the question.

Comment: Use $filter in case when you have more than one matching entry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use positional [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator to limit the contents of an array from the query results to contain only the first element matching the query document like below :

```
db.collection.find({id: 1, "adress.type" : "home"}, {"name":1, "address.$":1});
```

But use **$** in the projection document of the find() method or the findOne() method when you **only need one particular array element** in selected documents.

To get all the matched elements in the array instead of the first element only, you can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter) aggregator to do that like below :

> This is New in Mongodb version 3.2.

```
[{
 "$match": {
   "address.type": "home"
 }
},
{
"$project": {
  "address": {
    "$filter": {
      "input": "$address",
      "as": "address",
      "cond": {
        "$eq": ["$$address.type", "home"]
      }
    }
  }
}
}]
```

Comment: Your answer is true if and only if there is one match. Please check my update in the question.

Comment: @mmu36478: I've updated my answer to get the multiple matches. Please check and let me know if it's working.

Answer (score 1):

try aggregation match and project the address.

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
                  { $match : {id: 1, "adress.type" : "home"}},
                  {$project : { adress: 1} } 
                   ]}.exec(function (err, doc) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        else callback(null, doc);
    });
```